# How to let choose the directory to save csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have this function with python that create a simple CSV outFile but i want that i choose the directory of save with windows explorer, my function :

```
def exporter():
    name_of_file="export"
    l = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
    completeName = os.path.abspath("C:\temp\%s.csv" % name_of_file)
    out = open(completeName,"w")
    for row in l:
        for column in row:
            out.write('%d;' % column)
            out.write('\n')
        out.close()

    QObject.connect(export, SIGNAL('clicked()'),exporter)
```

export is a QPushButton ,Thanks !

Comment: What's the point of this line: 'completeName = os.path.abspath("C:\temp\%s.csv" % name_of_file)'? You already have the absolute path

Comment: And consider using the csv module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

```
def exporter(directory='C:\temp\\'):
    name_of_file = "export"
    l = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
    completeName = os.path.abspath("C:/temp/%s.csv" % name_of_file)
    full_path = '%(directory)s\%(name_of_file)s.csv' % locals()
    out = open(full_path, "w")
    for row in l:
        for column in row:
            out.write('%d;' % column)
            out.write('\n')
        out.close()

    QObject.connect(export, SIGNAL('clicked()'),exporter)
```

Something like this will do the trick. Just pass in the path as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but sorry i obtain this error :
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/temp\\export'

Comment: I don't know how paths work on Windows, maybe it should be something like : 'C:/temp/export.csv'

Comment: Edited my post, it looks like it is using forward slashes as on Linux

Comment: Now it work but it save the file in the directory path parameter 'C:\temp\\' for this case but i hope is when i click the Button it open the explorer Windows and i chose the directory what i want to save i hope you understand me :/

Comment: Oh this is why you had the PyQt tag. Have a look at this then: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/dialogs/